# List the items filtered by COUNTIF function in Google Sheets

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this function that is filtering some entries but I would want a function to list those items.
How can I do this?

```
=COUNTIFS('ORDENS DE FABRICO'!H3:H996;"<" & TODAY(); 'ORDENS DE FABRICO'!I3:I996;"PENDENTE")+COUNTIFS('ORDENS DE FABRICO'!H3:H996;"<" & TODAY(); 'ORDENS DE FABRICO'!I3:I996;"PRODUÇÃO")+COUNTIFS('ORDENS DE FABRICO'!H3:H996;"<" & TODAY(); 'ORDENS DE FABRICO'!I3:I996;"INSPEÇÃO")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=filter( 
  'ORDENS DE FABRICO'!H3:I; 
  'ORDENS DE FABRICO'!H3:H < & today(); 
  regexmatch('ORDENS DE FABRICO'!I3:I; "(?i)PENDENTE|PRODUÇÃO|INSPEÇÃO") 
)
```